# fill Json data in to a dynamically generated table

Tags: java, jquery, json

I generate a table dynamically using jquery. this is the code for it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // to generate the table for given number of blocks
        var numberOfBlocks = ${projectDetails.noOfBlocks};
        var i;
        var _html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';

        _html += '<tr>';
        _html += '<th>Blockk No</th>';
        _html += '<th>Lott No</th>';
        _html += '<th>Extentt</th>';
        _html += '<th>Land Value</th>';
        _html += '<th>On Booking Amount</th>';
        _html += '</tr>';

        for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(numberOfBlocks); i++) {

            _html += '<tr class="tblRw" id="row'+i+'">';
            _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="blockNo'+i+'" value="'+i+'"></td>';
            _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="lotNo'+i+'" ></td>';
            _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="extent'+i+'"></td>';
            _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="land_value'+i+'"></td>';
            _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="onbookingamount'+i+'"></td>';
            _html += '</tr>';

        }

        _html += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = _html;
       });
```

I need to populate the table rows with the data which are in a `Jason` response returned from my controller class. This is how I do it.

```
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse  edit_blocks(@ModelAttribute(value="editblockbean") EditBlockBean editBlockBean , BindingResult result,ModelMap model) {

        JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
        }else{

            List<EditBlockBean> ebb = branchservice.getBlocksForEdit(editBlockBean.getTitle());

            res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
            res.setResult(ebb);

        }
        return res;
    }
```

My `Jason` response from controller class consists of a list of class objects. This is the class;

```
public class BlockBean {

    private String blockNo;
    private String lotNo;
    private String extent;
    private String landValue;
    private String onBookingAmount;

    // getters and setters

}
```

In `Jason` response, I have a list of `BlockBean` objects. I need to assign those object attributes such as `blockNo, lotNo, extent,....` in to the columns of each row in the dynamic table generated in the jsp page.

This is my `ajax` call to take the jason response.

```
         jQuery.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "/TFProject/edit_blocks.htm",
                data : "title=" + title + "&type=" +type,

                success : function(response) {

                    if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {

                        // I need to know the code here.

                    } else {
                        errorInfo = "";

                        for (i = 0; i < response.result.length; i++) {
                            errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) + ". "
                                    + response.result[i].code;
                        }
                        jQuery('#error').html(
                                "Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
                        jQuery('#info').hide('slow');
                        jQuery('#error').show('slow');
                    }
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Errorrrr: ' + e);
                }
            });
```

What I need to know is the code segment for populating the table rows with jason response details if the `Jason` response status is success.
Could you please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Parse your map to JSON array then use in javascript / jquery.

Comment: I have to do it in my controller class?? Isn't it? Then how can I return json object together with ModelAndView?

Comment: Can you return a string from Controller to view?

Comment: @ParkashKumar I edited the question and now I use json. now I need to know how to populate my table from json data

Comment: How does your JSON response look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response returning method should be like:

```
public@ResponseBody String edit_blocks(@ModelAttribute(value = "editblockbean") EditBlockBean editBlockBean, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {    
    List <EditBlockBean> editBlockBeanList = branchservice.getBlocksForEdit(editBlockBean.getTitle());
    String jsonResult = "";
    try {
        if (editBlockBeanList != null && !editBlockBeanList.isEmpty()) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for (EditBlockBean ebb: editBlockBeanList) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("blockNo", ebb.getBlockNo());
                jsonObject.put("lotNo", ebb.getLotNo());
                jsonObject.put("extent", ebb.getExtent());
                jsonObject.put("landValue", ebb.getLandValue());
                jsonObject.put("onBookingAmount", ebb.getOnBookingAmount());
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            }
            jsonResult = jsonArray.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        jsonResult = "";
        // append exception to log
    }
    return jsonResult;
}
```

And this is success part of AJAX method that will write HTML table:

```
if (response != null && response != "") {
    var EditBlockBeanArray = JSON.parse(response);

    var _html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    _html += '<tr>';
    _html += '<th>Blockk No</th>';
    _html += '<th>Lott No</th>';
    _html += '<th>Extentt</th>';
    _html += '<th>Land Value</th>';
    _html += '<th>On Booking Amount</th>';
    _html += '</tr>';

    var i = 0;
    while (i < EditBlockBeanArray.length) {
        var ebbObject = EditBlockBeanArray[i];

        _html += '<tr class="tblRw" id="row' + i + '">';
        _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="blockNo' + i + '" value="' + i + '">' + ebbObject.blockNo + '</td>';
        _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="lotNo' + i + '">' + ebbObject.lotNo + '</td>';
        _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="extent' + i + '">' + ebbObject.extent + '</td>';
        _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="land_value' + i + '">' + ebbObject.landValue + '</td>';
        _html += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" size="10" id="onbookingamount' + i + '">' + ebbObject.onBookingAmount + '</td>';
        _html += '</tr>';

        i++;
    }

    _html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = _html;
} else {
    /* Your error code goes here */
}
```

Comment: This is only idea, you might need to modify to meet your requirement.

Comment: I am trying as you suggested. But I got an error at `jsonArray.put(jsonObject);` saying `The method put(JSONObject) is undefined for the type JSONArray`

Comment: Are you using org.json.JSONArray as import for JSONArray Class? http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: Also, you would require respective jar for this library.

Comment: yes I am using org.json.JSONArray. I added that jar to class path. what is the issue then?

Comment: I use 'json-simple-1.1.1.jar' library

Comment: Check your JSONArray Class, does it not contain the put method? I am sure, you are using some other library / older version. json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html This link shows that this class has put method.

Comment: I have uploaded the JAR, I have been using at the above path. You can verify using that jar file.

Comment: I get an error saying `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`.

Comment: Don't parse generated jsonResult (String) to JsonResponse. Also change public@ResponseBody JsonResponse edit_blocks to public@ResponseBody String edit_blocks and return jsonResult as return result.

Comment: could you please edit your answer for that. I got an alert from error section of json response. I did what you said

Comment: thank you very much ! It works. but one thing, I cannot mark this answer as an accepted answer since it should be edited. Actually ` res.setStatus("FAIL"); res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());` part should be removed from the code. Otherwise some one who refer this answer will not understand what it is. Thanks thank you again. You were the only man helped me. pls correct that issue. I need to accept your answer as the correct answer. thanks!

Comment: But, my answer does not contain this line: `res.setStatus("FAIL"); or res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());`. I had updated my answer with all required changes.